# For generic data block is there any advantage to use void* over uint8_t* or char*?

Tags: c++, pointers, casting

I am working on a system that passes data from one "location" to another. The passing of the data is to be sent as a data block where the sending mechanism knows nothing of its contents but the end points do.

Generally for this type of application I store my data as a block of uint8_t (unsigned 8-bit integers) i.e. bytes.

In one scenario the end points may store int16_t data elements and I will have to use somthing like:

```
pWord = reinterpret_cast<int16_t *>(pData);
```

In another scenario it could be:

```
pMyClass = reinterpret_cast<MyClass *>(pData);
```

Note: `uint8_t *pData;`

I have seen others use void* as the "generic" data block, or even char*. In my mind an uint8_t is the most basic kind of element and is the obvious choice, but I am wondering if there is any advantage in using other data types like void*. For example are there conversion rules for void* such that you can use static_cast instead of reinterpret_cast?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are some subtle differences. A `void *` pointer can not be used to access the contents of the data directly. It will ALWAYS have to be cast [perhaps implicitly by passing it to another function, such as memcpy, fread, or similar] into a different type. Whether this is "important" or not is a different question. For most intents and purposes, it is not particularly important.

In C++ there is really not that many places where you (should) need to do this, since templates and inheritance in various combinations allow you to do similar things with proper type safety.

In strict C++ standard perspective, you can't arbitrarily cast "any data" to `int16_t` - this may well work in some compilers on some types of processors, but on others, it may well fail (e.g. some processors are picky about addresses being aligned, and if you have some data of type `char` or `uint8_t` that you are converting `int16_t`, the compiler is not obliged to make sure it's aligned correctly for use in the latter form - this is just one scenario, there are many others where it could go wrong). The language does define access to data of "different type" from `char` or `unsigned char` (aka `uint8_t`) types, so this is safe.

Comment: I think a point worth mentioning is that `void *` is guaranteed to be able to hold any pointer type, whereas `uint8_t *` is not. That's a good reason to choose `void  *` over `uint8_t *`.

Comment: @FilipeGonçalves While what you say is true in general, `uint8_t` is sort of an exception; it is (indirectly) required to be a typedef to `unsigned char` or `char`.  And for historical reasons, a `char*` is required to have the same size and representation as a `void*` (and `unsigned X*` is required to be compatible with `X*`).

Comment: Actually both "having to cast" and "able to hold any pointer" are very good reasons for me, I prefer to be explicit where I can.

Comment: @code_fodder As long as the pointer is generic, I may hope? :) I prefer `void *` because it is the argument to `memcpy`, and because for truly generic datatypes you will HAVE to use `memcpy`.

Answer (score 1):

passing a input buffer using char* or void* is something used in C, not C++(since it provides other mechanisms). Here are a few points as to why you would use one or the other:

1. void* is used to pass a buffer of RAW data - you always need to do a cast to interpret the data
2. you may choose void* instead of char* because of conversion convenience: you can cast from void* to any other pointer type, but char* is limited to compiler defined data types ( you can't do a cast from char* to struct myType*)
3. you use char* when you want a straight forward way of specifying the size of a buffer: `void foo(char* array, int size N)` will give you an immediate idea of the size of the buffer.

There may be other reasons for using one or the other but the main thing is that most of these reasons are useful in C

Comment: Its true in c++ you can use a vector or similar. But in a vector you have to specify what type the contents is - you can't use "void", or at least it does not make sense to try that! If I setup a `vector<uint8_t> data` to hold some data, and then I want to "transform" the data into int16_t (in my case I am doing an interpolation on each such that byte --> word) then you have a vector of uint8 containing int16 data. I could move this to another vector, but I want to use the same memory space and avoid extra copies. So I have resorted to a more c-style approach of accessing the data by pointer..

Comment: you don't need to move the data to a different vector; you can simply have a pointer pointing at the start of the array(vector which is a wrapper for array) and interpret that memory how ever you like. But that would make using a vector, pointless to begin with. It sound to me like you are not asking the correct question here :)

Comment: In fact that is what I have ended up doing in some cases (i.e. use a vector as a wrapper for an array). I would not go so far as to say its "pointless" to use a vector, because you still have access to many useful features of the vector (like size, resize, clear... well, all of them!), it is just perfectly suited to "generic" contents.

Comment: well, I hope you got your answer

Comment: err.... meant to say "not perfectly suited to generic contents", sorry, I was not being disagreeable :o    +1 for your insights anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

In principle, `char*` or `uint8_t*` implies memory that can read/written to at the granularity of bytes, which is not always true. That's why `void*` is best used for untyped memory.

For example, the VRAM of the Gameboy Advance can only be used with 16-bit read/writes.

Comment: -1: the language guarantees that any pointer type can be safely cast to `char *` and back again into its original type without loss of information. So your assumption is wrong. `char *` is always a safe choice, even if it's there just for historical reasons.

Comment: Being able to cast it back and forth is one thing. Being able to read/write at a byte-by-byte level is another.

Comment: For example: http://www.coranac.com/tonc/text/bitmaps.htm
"VRAM vs byte writes:

You cannot write individual bytes into VRAM (or PALRAM or OAM for that matter). Halfwords or words only, please. If you want to write single bytes, you have to read the full (half)word, insert the byte, and put it back. "

Comment: Re the first sentence: C and C++ require byte-addressable memory in order to be implemented.  (How this is done, of course, is implementation defined, and may require some emulation.  A long time ago, I worked on a 16 bit word addressed machine where a `char*` required 2 words, and accessing through it generated 5 or 6 machine instructions.)

Comment: @NicolasLouisGuillemot At the machine code level.  C++ requires byte addressing at the C++ level.  (Of course, the implementation is free to define a byte to be 16 bits.  Or two generate extra code when accessing through a `char*`.)

Comment: Even if it can addressed at the level of bytes, it can't necessarily be read/written to at that granularity. I'll try to modify my answer to reflect that.

Comment: This is true, another example are various DSPs (TI5500, etc), in which case I would suggest it is up to the implementation within that particular code to "pack/unpack" the data as required, but +1 for mentioning 16-bit addressing though :)